# Simple 8 Puzzle - ASCII

Tags: c++, c++11, game, sliding-tile-puzzle

I made a simple 8 puzzle which is 3x3 grids unsorted. The user has to move only one number at any direction, which is next to an empty tile. If the user sorted numbers, he/she wins the game, otherwise he/she needs to restart the game.

The game seems to work fine, but I would like to know how I can improve it further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <conio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.141592653589793238462643383f
#endif 

namespace
{
    enum KeyType
    {
        KUp = 72,
        KRight = 77,
        KLeft = 75,
        KDown = 80
    };

    enum  Direction
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right,
        DirectionCount
    };

    std::mt19937 randomEngine()
    {
        std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
        thread_local std::random_device source;
        std::generate(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data), std::ref(source));
        std::seed_seq seeds(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
        thread_local std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
        return seeded_engine;
    }

    float radian(Direction direction)
    {
        constexpr static std::array<float, Direction::DirectionCount> Radians
        {
            M_PI,       // Up
            0,          // Down
            -M_PI / 2,  // Left
            M_PI / 2    // Right
        };

        return Radians[direction];
    }
}

struct Vector
{
    Vector(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) 
        :x(x)
        , y(y)
    {}

    unsigned int x, y;
};

class Puzzle
{
private:
    constexpr static auto MaxTiles = 9u;
    constexpr static auto Columns = 3u;

    using Pair = std::pair<Vector, unsigned int>;
    using TileHolder = std::array<char, MaxTiles>;


public:
    Puzzle()
    {
        std::iota(mTiles.begin(), mTiles.end(), '1');
        mTiles.back() = ' ';

        thread_local auto random = randomEngine();

        std::shuffle(mTiles.begin(), mTiles.end(), random);
    }

    void update(Direction direction)
    {
        const auto& coord = getEmptyTileCoordinates();

        auto x = static_cast<unsigned int>(coord.first.x - std::sin(radian(direction)));
        auto y = static_cast<unsigned int>(coord.first.y - std::cos(radian(direction)));

        if (x < 0u || x >= 3u || y < 0u || y >= 3u) return;

        std::swap(mTiles[y * Columns + x], mTiles[coord.second]);
    }

    bool isSorted() const
    {
        return std::is_sorted(mTiles.begin(), mTiles.end() - 1);
    }


private:
    Pair getEmptyTileCoordinates() const
    {
        auto found = std::find(mTiles.cbegin(), mTiles.cend(), ' ');

        assert(found != mTiles.cend());

        auto index = std::distance(mTiles.cbegin(), found);
        auto coord = Vector(index % Columns, index / Columns);

        return{ coord, index };
    }

    void draw(std::ostream& stream) const
    {
        for (const auto& tile : mTiles)
        {
            auto index = &tile - &*(mTiles.begin());
            stream << tile << ((index % Columns == Columns - 1) ? '\n' : ' ');
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Puzzle& puzzle)
    {
        puzzle.draw(stream);
        return stream;
    }


private:
    TileHolder mTiles;
};

class Game 
{
    using KeysMap = std::map<int, Direction>;


public:
    Game()
    {
        mKeyBinding.emplace(KeyType::KUp, Direction::Up);
        mKeyBinding.emplace(KeyType::KDown, Direction::Down);
        mKeyBinding.emplace(KeyType::KLeft, Direction::Left);
        mKeyBinding.emplace(KeyType::KRight, Direction::Right);
    }

    void gameLoop()
    {
        display();

        while (!mPuzzle.isSorted())
        {
            if (_kbhit())
            {
                userInput();
                display();
            }
        }

        result();
    }


private:
    void userInput()
    {
        auto found = mKeyBinding.find(_getch());

        if (found != mKeyBinding.end())
            mPuzzle.update(found->second);
    }

    void display()
    {
        system("cls");

        std::cout << mPuzzle;
    }

    void result()
    {
        std::cout << "yey: it sorted!";
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    Puzzle mPuzzle;
    KeysMap mKeyBinding;
};

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.gameLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with **update**.

Since `getEmptyTileCoordinates()` returns a `Pair`, you can store that in `coord` instead of using a reference:

```
auto coord(getEmptyTileCoordinates());
```

For the direction offsets, you can just have arrays that store the x and y offsets for a particular direction rather than doing the math with floats.

```
// in local namespace
const int x_offset[] = {0, 0, -1, +1};  // Up, Down, Left, Right
const int y_offset[] = {-1, +1, 0, 0};

// in update
unsigned x = coord.first.x + x_offset[direction];
unsigned y = coord.first.y + y_offset[direction];
```

That would allow you to get rid of your `radian` function.  And since `x` and `y` are `unsigned`, they'll never be less than zero and you don't need to check them for that (although the compiler will know this and likely will optimize away those comparisons).

**draw**

You're doing a lot of work in `draw` to determine when to use a newline instead of a space.  This can be simplified by using a counter.

```
void draw(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    int column = 0;
    for (const auto& tile : mTiles)
    {
        column = (column + 1) % Columns;
        stream << tile << (column == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
}
```