# Simple 8 Puzzle - ASCII - follow up

Tags: c++, c++11, game, sliding-tile-puzzle

Based on the [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117440/simple-8-puzzle-ascii), I have implemented all suggestions with slight modifications. The game seems fine, are there any further improvements needed in this game?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <conio.h>


template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
    Vector(T x, T y): x(x), y(y){}
    T x, y;
};

using Vector2i = Vector<int>;
using Vector2u = Vector<unsigned int>;

namespace Key
{
    enum Type
    {
        Up = 72,
        Right = 77,
        Left = 75,
        Down = 80
    };
}

namespace Direction
{
    enum Type
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right,
        DirectionCount
    };
}

namespace utility
{
    std::mt19937 randomEngine()
    {
        std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
        thread_local std::random_device source;
        std::generate(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end(), std::ref(source));
        std::seed_seq seeds(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end());
        thread_local std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
        return seeded_engine;
    }

    Vector2i directionOffset(Direction::Type direction)
    {
        using OffsetHolder = std::array<int, Direction::DirectionCount>;

        constexpr static OffsetHolder xOffset{ 0, 0, +1, -1 };
        constexpr static OffsetHolder yOffset{ +1, -1, 0, 0 };

        return{ xOffset[direction], yOffset[direction] };
    }
}

namespace ut = utility;

class Puzzle
{
private:
    constexpr static auto MaxTiles = 9u;
    constexpr static auto Columns = 3u;

    using Pair = std::pair<Vector2u, unsigned int>;
    using TileHolder = std::array<char, MaxTiles>;


public:
    Puzzle()
    {
        std::iota(mTiles.begin(), mTiles.end(), '1');
        mTiles.back() = ' ';

        thread_local auto random = ut::randomEngine();

        std::shuffle(mTiles.begin(), mTiles.end(), random);
    }

    void update(Direction::Type direction)
    {
        auto coord = getEmptyTileCoordinates();

        auto x = coord.first.x + ut::directionOffset(direction).x;
        auto y = coord.first.y + ut::directionOffset(direction).y;

        if (x >= 3u  || y >= 3u) return;

        std::swap(mTiles[y * Columns + x], mTiles[coord.second]);
    }

    bool isSorted() const
    {
        return std::is_sorted(mTiles.begin(), mTiles.end() - 1);
    }


private:
    Pair getEmptyTileCoordinates() const
    {
        auto found = std::find(mTiles.cbegin(), mTiles.cend(), ' ');

        assert(found != mTiles.cend());

        auto index = std::distance(mTiles.cbegin(), found);
        auto coord = Vector2u(index % Columns, index / Columns);

        return{ coord, index };
    }

    void draw(std::ostream& stream) const
    {
        auto column = 0u;
        for (const auto& tile : mTiles)
        {
            ++column %= Columns;
            stream << tile << (column == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Puzzle& puzzle)
    {
        puzzle.draw(stream);
        return stream;
    }


private:
    TileHolder mTiles;
};

class Game 
{
private:
    using KeysMap = std::map<int, Direction::Type>;


public:
    Game()
    {
        mKeyBinding.emplace(Key::Up, Direction::Up);
        mKeyBinding.emplace(Key::Down, Direction::Down);
        mKeyBinding.emplace(Key::Left, Direction::Left);
        mKeyBinding.emplace(Key::Right, Direction::Right);
    }

    void gameLoop()
    {
        display();

        while (!mPuzzle.isSorted())
        {
            if (!_kbhit()) continue;

            userInput();
            display();
        }

        result();
    }


private:
    void userInput()
    {
        auto found = mKeyBinding.find(_getch());

        if (found == mKeyBinding.end()) return;

        mPuzzle.update(found->second);
    }

    void display()
    {
        system("cls");
        std::cout << mPuzzle;
    }

    void result()
    {
        std::cout << "yey: it sorted!";
        std::cin.ignore();
    }


private:
    Puzzle mPuzzle;
    KeysMap mKeyBinding;
};

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.gameLoop();
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your namespace/enum by using the c++11 enum class which is a bit less verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't use `system("cls")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example, if your terminal supports [ANSI Escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you could use this:

```
void cls()
{
    std::cout << "\x1b[2J";
}
```

### Isolate platform-specific code

In this code, there are several things that are DOS/Windows only including `#include <conio.h>` and the `getch()` and `kbhit()` functions within that, and also `system("cls");` that I've already mentioned.  Your code runs successfully on Linux if I supply those missing functions, but it would be nice if there were an `#ifdef WINDOWS` already in the code so that one could recompile without having to alter the source code.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `std::ref` but doesn't `#include <functional>`.

### Fix the initialization

The initialization of the puzzle does not always result in a solvable puzzle.  In fact, exactly half of all possible states are impossible to solve.  This is a bit frustrating for anyone actually trying to solve the puzzle, so I'd recommend a different initialization that *only* results in solvable puzzles.

### Don't abuse namespaces

The namespacess in this program seem excessive to me.  In particular, I was annoyed by this line:

```
namespace ut = utility;
```

If you find the name `utility` too long, change it.  If you don't, then use it as is.  It's only used three places anyway.

### Don't abuse `auto`

I'm a fan of `auto` generally, but when I see lines like this:

```
auto column = 0u;
```

it makes me question why it's being used.  It seems to be written almost as though the point were obfuscation.

### Write code for *clarity*

Let's imagine that you've just been asked to add a feature to this code and it's the first time you've seen it.  You look at this line in `Puzzle`:

```
Pair getEmptyTileCoordinates() const
```

So what is a `Pair`?  You scan the code and find this line:

```
using Pair = std::pair<Vector2u, unsigned int>;
```

Great.  So what's a `Vector2u`?  More hunting until you find this:

```
using Vector2u = Vector<unsigned int>;
```

By now you are cursing the name of the original programmer.  What is a `Vector`?  It's this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
    Vector(T x, T y): x(x), y(y){}
    T x, y;
};
```

So now you're four levels of indirection away and have probably forgotten what started you on this chain of lookups in the first place. Even more frustrating is that each of these is only used exactly once in the program, so there's little point to most of it.  **Don't do this!**  Write for clarity instead.

### Keep `private` data together

Both the `Game` and the `Puzzle` classes have three different places where `private:` is used.  Again, this makes things more confusing than they need to be.  Instead, put all of the `private` parts together.  I recommend putting functions first and then data.

### Make static data `static`

The `mKeyBinding` member of the doesn't change (so it should be `const`) and is also invariant across `Puzzle` instantiations.  This strongly suggests that it should instead be `static`.  Change the declaration to this:

```
static const std::map<int, Direction::Type> mKeyBinding;
```

Then outside the class, initialize it like this:

```
const std::map<int, Direction::Type> Game::mKeyBinding{ 
    {Key::Up, Direction::Up},
    {Key::Down, Direction::Down},
    {Key::Left, Direction::Left},
    {Key::Right, Direction::Right}
};
```

Note that I've also dropped yet another `typedef` to clarify the code.

### Place `friend` declarations in a `public` section

A `friend` declaration is always public no matter if it's declared within the `private` or `public` sections.  For clarity, put it in the `public` section unless there is a very good reason not to (and there is almost never a good reason).